# Google maps autocomplete box size

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete

I have a text input for an address that is about 150px wide. I have Google autocomplete linked to it, but because the input box is so small, the Google autocomplete is also as small as the input. I want the autocomplete to open full size, so I can actually read the addresses it is providing. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

class pac-input

```
.pac-input {
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-left: 12px;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 400px;
      }
```